# Email an attachment with non-ascii filename with python email

Tags: python, email, unicode, character-encoding, rfc2231

How can I send an email with a file attached where the file name contains unicode characters?

Up to now, the file will arrive but with the filename *"noname"*.

This is the part that works perfectly well for ASCII filenames:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.Utils import formatdate
from email import Encoders
from email.Utils import encode_rfc2231

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = "New magazine delivery!"
msg['From'] = sender_email
msg['To'] = ', '.join(kindle_emails)
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
message = "see attachment"
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
part = MIMEApplication(open(f, 'rb').read(), _subtype='application/x-mobipocket-ebook')

part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename(filename)
msg.attach(part)
```

**First try**

Adding a tuple of encoding, language and encoded string and not only the filename.

```
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=('utf-8', 'fr', os.path.basename(f).encode('utf-8')))
```

**Second try:**

Setting the charset globally like this:

```
from email import Charset
Charset.add_charset('utf-8', Charset.QP, Charset.QP, 'utf-8')
```

**Third try**

Using `utils.encode_rfc2231`

```
from email.Utils import encode_rfc2231
utf8filename = encode_rfc2231(os.path.basename(f).encode('utf-8'), charset='utf-8')
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=('utf-8', 'fr', utf8filename))
```

**Fourth try**

Using `urllib.quote()` to urlencode the filename. This has the same effect on the filename as the third method.

```
utf8filename = urllib.quote(os.path.basename(f).encode('utf-8'))
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=('utf-8', 'fr', utf8filename))
```

Any ideas?

Am I missing something essential about RFC2231 filename character encoding?

I use Gmail's SMTP server and python 2.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of telling the server that it's UTF-8 like this:

```
filename=('utf-8', 'fr', os.path.basename(f).encode('utf-8'))
```

...it works when I just send UTF-8 without telling so:

```
filename=os.path.basename(f).encode('utf-8')
```

The file name will be properly displayed.

This seems to contradict the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html) which states:

> If the value contains non-ASCII characters, it must be specified as a
> three tuple in the format (CHARSET, LANGUAGE, VALUE), where CHARSET is
> a string naming the charset to be used to encode the value, LANGUAGE
> can usually be set to None or the empty string (see RFC 2231 for other
> possibilities), and VALUE is the string value containing non-ASCII
> code points.

This doesn't work, however the [python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) adds: .

> If a three tuple is not passed and the value contains non-ASCII
> characters, it is automatically encoded in RFC 2231 format using a
> CHARSET of utf-8 and a LANGUAGE of None.

Only this works, even for python 2.7, though it's not mentioned in the docs.

Comment: double )) at the end of statement.

Answer (score 1):

as [Suzana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663614/suzana) points out, from [python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html), you don't need to encode the utf-8 filename, just let the library do it for you:

```
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=('utf-8', '', filename))
```

This is working correctly with python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

I tried much ways to solve this problem. Finally I found following codes can work correctly

```py
  basename = Header(os.path.basename(file_path), 'utf-8').encode()
  file.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=basename)
```